Dynamically injected component's data is not being displayed in main component in Angular
I am currently trying to display a component's html view in another component in a chatbot setting. Let's call them chat component and component 2. So basically chat component which renders the main chatbot view, displays component 2's html view when certain conditions are met. If those certain conditions are met, chat component passes data to component 2. Component 2 html view is a table. I am using [ngComponentOutlet] in my chat.component.html to display component 2's html view but only the table head of component 2 is displayed on chat.component.html and not the table body. I'm not sure what's the problem
//chat.component.ts snippet
 messages: Message[]=[]
 const newMessage:Message={"text":response.gptResponse,"sender":"Your Booking Companion",
                                    "timeStamp":new Date(),"component":Component2} 
          this.messages.push(newMessage);
          console.log(this.messages)`

//chat.component.html
`<ng-container *ngFor="let message of messages; let i=index">
            <div class="mb-3 col-10 position-relative bottom-0 start-50 translate-middle-x">
                <span class="message_sender">{{message.sender}}</span>
                    <p>{{message.text}}</p>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="message.component">
                        <ng-template [ngComponentOutlet]="message.component"></ng-template>
                    </ng-container>
            </div>    
        </ng-container>   

//message.ts
export interface Message{
    text: string
    sender: string
    timeStamp: Date
    component?:Type<any>
}

//component2.component.html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>_some_header_</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of someData">
            <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

I tried using @Output() dataLoaded = new EventEmitter(); in my component2.component.ts to emit an Event to my chat.component.ts and use setTimeOut() in my chat.component.ts to listen for it before pushing the newMessage to messages array because i thought maybe component2 needed some time to take in the input from chat component but that didn't seem to work.
I even console.log() in component 2 to see if the data was passed to it from chat component, and it indeed was passed to component 2. Since, component 2 did take in the data from chat component, i don't know why chat component cannot dynamically display the table rendered in component 2

EDIT : staring from version 16.2.0 there is a simpler solution using inputs binding.
You can simply do as this in chat.component.html :
<ng-template [ngComponentOutlet]="message.component; inputs: { someData: someData }"></ng-template>

And define @Input() someData:SomeData; in componant2.component.ts

Version older than 16.2.0 solution :
You certainly need to provide an injector to the child component for it to access someData.
In chat.component.ts :

constructor(injector: Injector) {

    // loop over messages
    message.myInjector = Injector.create({providers: [{ provide: SomeData, useValue: someData }], parent: injector});
  }

In chat.component.html
<ng-template [ngComponentOutlet]="message.component; injector: message.myInjector"></ng-template>

Finally in component2.component.ts
constructor(public someData: SomeData) {}

See https://docs.angular.lat/api/common/NgComponentOutlet
EDIT: SomeData certainly needs to be decorated with @Injectable()
